# htaccess - rewrite .shtml and .html as . php

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, shtml

I'm pretty green with mod_rewrite. I've got the first line of this working like a champ, but the second part refuses to cooperate

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^(.*).shtml$ $1.php [R=301,L]
```

The `.shtml` part fails wonderfully and 404s - without my custom 404 page. Should this be combined in to one rule? Should I quit my job and let them hire a monkey to replace me? has anyone got a solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain (in words) which extension redirects to what? Can monkeys do rewrites?

Comment: @SalmanA A million monkeys at a million keyboards over a million years would eventually redirect all `.html` requests to `www.nationalgeographic.com`.

Comment: @Salman A
1. I need both .html and .shtml to be rewritten as .php
2. If I can, I can't imagine a monkey is that far off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are intending to redirect both `.shtml` and `.html` to `.php`...

These should both be combined into one rule, and the problem looks to be that both match because the unescaped `.` before `.html` stands for "any character", which therefore also matches `shtml`.

The pattern `\.s?html` will match the literal `.`, followed by an *optional* `s`, and ending with `html`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.s?html$ $1.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Ah! Your technical point makes sense. Thank you for the clarification. Your suggestion, however, fails for me. I get a redirection complaint from IE and FF along the lines of "The page isn't redirecting properly". any other ideas?

Comment: @AmeliaEarhart You would have to look in the web server access and error logs. If it is entering a rewrite loop, that may be because of some other rewrite rule in this directory, or in another directory.  As it is above, there's no way a .php request would match this rule and go into a rewrite loop.

Comment: Do you want to actually redirect the browser to `.php`, or silently serve the `.php` script without the browser knowing about it? ( if silently, remove the R=301)

Comment: Yup. That was it. I'd been messing around with .htaccess in a subdir - forgotten about that. Problem solved. Thank you, Michael.